# Replace the whole project - Everything is up-to-date

Tags: git, github

I'm newbie in ***git***, 2 years ago I have published a project of mine (*final year training project*).
Now I have make some changes to change the project structure (I *separate* the project to be **Library** + **Sample**) also I have changed the *build tool*. So to achieve that I have the idea to :

1. Clone the project `git clone url`
2. Remove completely the project `git rm *`
3. Copy past the new project structure and `git add *`
4. Commit the changes `git commit`
5. Push the changes locally/remotely `git push` and `git push origin master`

The problem that I still get `Everything is up-to-date`

**Note :** I already applied the different solutions suggest for `Everything is up-to-date` but without result

#### EDIT

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .idea/workspace.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in wakadroid.iml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in wakadroidlib/wakadroidlib.iml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in wakadroidsample/wakadroidsample.iml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Comment: Why not make a whole separate project instead of blowing away everything in the old one then adding everything back?

Comment: because I have some stars in the project and if I create a new project I will lose them

Answer (score 0):

Did you do `git push` followed by `git push origin master`? In a fresh clone those will be the same thing (provided you were making your changes on the master branch). This means that the first one you did pushed the changes, then the second had nothing left to do.

Comment: same result when I did `git push origin master` without `git push` => `Everything is up-to-date `

Comment: Right, but at this point if you've already successfully pushed once then any subsequent push will say that it's up to date, because it is. Do you have your console log from the very first time you pushed? If so, paste that into your question. Paste in the response to your commit as well, in case that failed.

Comment: yeah I get some log console

Comment: Solved but using Git Gui

Answer (score 0):

Use `git add .` instead of git add *